# Как передать глобальную переменную в текст, python telebot telegram?

Tags: python-3.6, telebot

Задача.
Установить глобальную переменную. Которую можно использовать на протяжении действия всего скрипта.
При старте, крошится и на момента отправки стикера.

```html
import telebot
import config
import random
 
from telebot import types
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

i = ('text1_items')
x = ('text2_Kypon')
z = ('text3_wallet')
y = ('text4_helps')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('avatar1459.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    # keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton(text=i)
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton(text=x)
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton(text=z)
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton(text=y)

  
    markup.add(items, item2, item3, item4)
 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный чтобы быть подопытным кроликом.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
        parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
            
def message_handler(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'hello':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Have a nice day!")
        if '6kzujg-bk7bhh-snlfqr' in message.text:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Да друг твой код готов к обработке")
        if 'ga4y7n-38p5z2-m1ugot' in message.text:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Да друг твой код готов к обработке 1")    
        if '5gva57-7jtj5p-vldrck' in message.text:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Да друг твой код готов к обработке 2")
        if '5nf1yi-m5c9ij-gtm3f8' in message.text:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Да друг твой код готов к обработке 3")             
        elif message.text == 'Пополнить':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,100)))
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(random.randint(0,100)))   
        elif message.text == ' Рандомное число':
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не пью')
        elif message.text == '23':    
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')  

        elif message.text == ' Как дела?':
 
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Хорошо", callback_data='good')
            item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Не очень", callback_data='bad')
 
            markup.add(item1, item2)
 
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично, сам как?', reply_markup=markup)
        #else:
            # bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не знаю что ответить ')

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    try:
        if call.message:
            if call.data == 'good':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Вот и отличненько ')
            elif call.data == 'bad':
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Бывает ')
 
            # remove inline buttons
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=" Как дела?",
                reply_markup=None)
 
            # show alert
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id, show_alert=False,
                text="ЭТО ТЕСТОВОЕ УВЕДОМЛЕНИЕ!!11")
 
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))
# RUN
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

можно использовать глобальную переменную в пределах хэндлера

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    global f_name
    f_name= message.text
    print(f_name)

def one():
    print(f_name)

def two():
    print(f_name)

etc.


@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop'])
def stop(message):
    global f_name  # это уже другая переменная
    f_name= message.text
    print(f_name)

def one_1():
    print(f_name)

def two_2():
    print(f_name)

etc.
```

но глобалки зло, лучше сделайте класс. [здесь есть пример](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py)

Answer (score 2):

На моменте со стикером у тебя ошибка, тк в тг свое расширение файла для стикера (.webp), а у тебя обычная картинка jpg. Можешь сделать так:

`bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, sti)`

Про переменную сказать не могу, вывод консоли можешь скинуть ?